# Nested search bool query with must and should operators

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying a nested aggregation and to apply a filter on it.

See the following example:

**Car**

- brand
- name
- features

**Features**

- name
- value

Here's some test data:

```
car_A:
{
 brand :"VW",
 name: "Golf",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "black"},
  {name: "power", value: "150"}
 ]
}

car_B:
{
 brand :"VW",
 name: "Golf",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "blue"},
  {name: "power", value: "150"}
 ]
}

car_C:
{
 brand :"VW",
 name: "Golf",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "white"},
  {name: "power", value: "150"}
 ]
}

car_D:
{
 brand :"BMW",
 name: "X3",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "white"},
  {name: "power", value: "180"}
 ]
}

car_E:
{
 brand :"BMW",
 name: "X5",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "blue"},
  {name: "power", value: "250"}
 ]
}

car_F:
{
 brand :"BMW",
 name: "X3",
 features: [
  {name: "color", value: "blue"},
  {name: "power", value: "150"}
 ]
}
```

and here's the query:

```
"query": {
"nested": {
  "path": "features",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "features.color": "blue"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "features.color": "white"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "features.power": 150
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
 }
}
```

The query result is A,B,C,F

The expected result should be B,C,F (color=blue **OR** color=white) **AND** power=150

Comment: I think your result was correct because `A` also contains `power=150`

Comment: The problem is right there, since features.color in A is not "blue" and is not  "white", the OR should fail in normal logic. The should operator does not behave in this way. Do you think I should change the query to a AND and OR filter to achieve the expected result? (in production the query has an aggregation also)

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```
"query": {
"nested": {
  "path": "features",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "features.color": "blue"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "features.color": "white"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "features.power": 150
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Meaning, the fields that you use in the query should be prefixed with the name of the `path`: `features.color`, `features.power`.

**EDIT**:

Try this query (I missed the essential here - you need two `must`s, one being a `bool` with `should`s):

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "features",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "features.power": 150
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "features.color": "blue"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "features.color": "white"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Stefan, you are right, in my example the path name was missing. The problem is still there even if I specify (I have to) the path prefix.

Comment: You're right, the problem is somewhere else. I updated my answer.